# Is it somehow possible to *live* modify Python code (like in Lisp or Erlang)

Tags: python, erlang, lisp

I was wondering if it is somehow possible to modify Python code live, while keeping all state of instantiated objects and methods, like I *think* is possible in Lisp or Erlang (*) ?

Say, I have an active Python sessions, where I instantiated the `foo` class from a self-written module:

```
class foo():
   @classmethod
   def do_something(self):
       print "this is good"
```

Python command line:

```
>>> f =foo()
>>> f.do_something()
```

Now, I would like to change the print statement into something else (e.g. `print "this is better"`). If I edit my module file to do so, and reload it, I have to re-instantiate the `f` object. Is there a way to be able to just call `f.do_something()` again without having to call `f=foo()` first?

So, I have to do this:

```
>>> reload my_module
>>> f =foo()
>>> f.do_something() # with changed print statement
```

But I want to do this:

```
>>> reload my_module
>>> f.do_something() # with changed print statement
```

(*) I am basing this statement on the [cool Erlang movie](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uKfKtXYLG78) and this fragment from [Practical Common Lisp](http://www.gigamonkeys.com/book/lather-rinse-repeat-a-tour-of-the-repl.html): '*When the bug manifested in the wild--100 million miles away from Earth--the team was able **to diagnose and fix the running code**, allowing the experiments to complete.*'

**Edit:** I've been thinking a bit more about this and maybe what I want is inherently flawed for applying to OO (i.e., what about the state of the class and methods). I think Erlang allows this because, as far as I recall, it is more about separate communicating objects, so live updating the code of an object makes more sense. I am not sure though, so still open for answers.

**Edit2:** Maybe the best way to describe what I want is recapitulate what I said in a comment in a post below: "When called, the methods just have to point to the new method definitions/locations."

Comment: Your desire to hot-swap code is definitely not inherently flawed in an OO setting. Since you mentioned Lisp: Common Lisp has got an object system, and there, changing a class indeed affects all of its instances immediately. The existing state of an object is preserved as far as it is compatible with the new class definition, and more elaborate class redefinition behavior can be defined manually by defining a method for the generic function update-instance-for-redefined-class. I believe that Ruby, which may be closer to a traditional object model, also updates instances when a class changes.

Comment: If you are forced to swap Python code running on a spaceship, and have access to a repl, you'd just monkey patch the class on the fly without resorting to anything as dangerous and as extreme as module reloading. :P

Answer (score 6):

Yes you can, pretty simple too.  You want to change only the instance `f`, not the class `foo`, right?

```
>>> class foo():
   @classmethod
   def do_something(self):
       print "this is good"


>>> f = foo()
>>> f.do_something()
this is good
>>> def new_ds():
        print "this is better"


>>> f.do_something = new_ds
>>> f.do_something()
    this is better

>>> f2 = foo()
>>> f2.do_something() #unchanged
    this is good
```

---

### EDIT

This is almost certainly less than desirable due to the change in scope, but changes like this took place for me immediately upon reload

testmod.py -- initially

```
class foo():
   @classmethod
   def do_something(self):
       outside_func()

def outside_func():
    print "this is good"
```

testmod.py -- after change

```
class foo():
   @classmethod
   def do_something(self):
       outside_func()

def outside_func():
    print "this is better"
```

Interpreter

```
>>> import testmod
>>> f = testmod.foo()
>>> f.do_something()
this is good
>>> reload(testmod)
<module 'testmod' from 'C:\Python26\testmod.py'>
>>> f.do_something()
this is better
```

Comment: or do you want to change source code living in a file somewhere?  i just read your question more closely and i think i misunderstood

Comment: Now you just have to get this to happen automatically when the module is reloaded.

Comment: so he does want the class changed, not just the instance?

Comment: He wants everything the module contains changed.

Comment: what part(s) make up 'the module'?  just the class definition?

Comment: That's all there is in this module, but presumably the answer should be flexible to account for every name a module may contain.

Comment: Actually, after reloading the module, I want the old `f` to still exist (which is already so), but have the `.do_something()` method point to the new method code.

Comment: @jon: clever solution, I didn't knew this was possible. But indeed, this has to apply for all methods that have changed (potentially in a file). So I guess that 'now you just have to get this to happen automatically when the module is reloaded' comes quite close to what I want...

Comment: so - the module contains a class definition `foo`, session has instantiated this class one or more times (`f1`, `f2`,...).  you want to edit the modules file and reload it in session, having the changes apply to ALL instances of `foo` automatically (no new inits)?

Comment: @jon: yes, although I would think about it in a different way. When called, the methods just have to point to the new method definitions/locations...

Comment: yes i follow.  the "hot swap" idea makes more sense in that context.  i get the LISP comparison now

Comment: For what it's worth, I toyed around with this and found that when I imported a module, instantiated a class from the module using `mod.Foo()`, made a change to the module, and reloaded it, the previously-created instance of `Foo` was not changed. However, if I defined a class within the current scope, or if I imported a class into the current scope using `from mod import Foo`, and then created an instance of `Foo`, and modified the class (`Foo.method = new_method`), the changes affected the previously-created instance.

Comment: @senderle: yes, I think that was exactly what jon showed in his post, no?

Comment: @Rabarberski, no, at least in the first version of his post, he changed the instance directly. In both my experiments, I changed the class definition -- I never touched the instance.

Comment: it sounds similar to what i did in my original post (not the edit), but the difference is that 1) he edited class instead of instance and 2) brought modules into the equation whereas i didnt even use a module the first time around

Comment: feels like there should be a way to do exactly what you want.  i wish i had a real mastery of the finer points of new/old objects, metaclasses, get/setattr and get/setattribute.  this stuff http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html

Answer (score 5):

You can create a class decorator or a metaclass that makes sure that the class of the old objects is changed on class reload. Here's a working (at least for me) example, though I wouldn't suggest you to use it as it is, but use it as an inspiration to create something that matches your intentions and needs. (It is also not tested on classes that don't define `__init__`, so be wary.)

```
import sys
import weakref

class _ObSet(weakref.WeakValueDictionary):
    def add(self, ob):
        self[id(ob)] = ob

    def remove(self, ob):
        del self[id(ob)]

    def __iter__(self):
        return self.itervalues()

def reloadable(cls):

    # Change the __init__ of the old class to store the instances
    # in cls.__instances (you might stick this into a class as a
    # static method to avoid name collisions)

    if '__init__' in vars(cls):
        old_init = vars(cls)['__init__']

        def __init__(self, *a, **kw):
            self.__class__.__instances.add(self)
            old_init(self, *a, **kw)

        cls.__init__ = __init__

    elif '__new__' in vars(cls):
        old_new = vars(cls)['__new__']

        def __new__(cls, *a, **kw):
            self = old_new(cls, *a, **kw)
            cls.__instances.add(self)
            return self

        cls.__new__ = __new__

    else:

        def __init__(self, *a, **kw):
            self.__class__.__instances.add(self)
            super(cls, self).__init__(*a, **kw)

        cls.__init__ = __init__

    cls.__instances = _ObSet()

    module = sys.modules.get(cls.__module__)
    if module is None:
        return cls

    old_cls = getattr(module, cls.__name__, None)
    if old_cls is None:
        return cls

    # Change the bases of all subclasses of the old class
    for ob in old_cls.__instances:
        if ob.__class__ is old_cls:
            ob.__class__ = cls

    # Change the class of all instances of the old class
    for child_cls in old_cls.__subclasses__():
        child_cls.__bases__ = tuple(cls if base is old_cls else base
                                    for base in child_cls.__bases__)

    return cls
```

Here's an example of how it is used:

```
from reloading import reloadable

@reloadable
class A(object):
    def __init__(self, a, b):
        self.a = a
        self.b = b


class B1(A):
    def __init__(self, c, *a):
        super(B1, self).__init__(*a)
        self.c = c

@reloadable
class B2(A):
    def __init__(self, c, *a):
        super(B2, self).__init__(*a)
        self.c = c
```

And then how it works:

```
>>> import test_reload
>>> a = test_reload.A(1, 2)
>>> b1 = test_reload.B1(1, 2, 3)
>>> b2 = test_reload.B2(1, 4, 6)
>>> isinstance(a, test_reload.A)
True
>>> isinstance(b1, test_reload.A)
True
>>> isinstance(b1, test_reload.B1)
True
>>> isinstance(b2, test_reload.A)
True
>>> isinstance(b2, test_reload.B2)
True
>>> reload(test_reload)
<module 'test_reload' from 'test_reload.pyc'>
>>> isinstance(a, test_reload.A)
True
>>> isinstance(b1, test_reload.A)
True
>>> isinstance(b1, test_reload.B1) # will fail, not @reloadable
False
>>> isinstance(b2, test_reload.A)
True
>>> isinstance(b2, test_reload.B2)
True
>>> a.a, a.b
(1, 2)
>>> b1.a, b1.b, b1.c
(2, 3, 1)
>>> b2.a, b2.b, b2.c
(4, 6, 1)
```

Comment: Actually, it just came to my mind that an easier way to achieve the same would be to modify the old class to work like the new one, and then return the old one from the decorator scraping the new one altogether. It also has the advantage that if the class itself is stored somewhere, it would also be changed without any work on your part.

Answer (score 0):

This shows that you can modify an existing class and have those changes be manifest in instances of that class. The key is to modify the existing class rather than (re)create a new class with the same name as the old class.

```
>>> class foo():
...     @classmethod
...     def do_something(self):
...         print "this is good"
... 
>>> f = foo()
>>> f.do_something()
this is good
>>> def do_something_else(self):
...     print "this is better"
... 
>>> foo.do_something = do_something_else
>>> f.do_something()
this is better
```